# Is it possible play free-for-all in LAN games?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Can I play against everyone in Global Offensive's LAN mode?

I tried to find a way but I only have two options, Terrorist & Counter Terrorist. Is there a free-for-all mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `mp_teammates_are_enemies 1`. This will turn your allies as well as your enemies into valid targets.

If you're in a local game you can just enter this in your console. On a server (LAN or Internet doesn't matter) you need to prefix it with `rcon` (and be logged in with the rcon password):

`rcon_address server-ip` (not needed when you're currently playing on that server)
`rcon_password ****`
`rcon mp_teammates_are_enemies 1`